# Kivy - is there a list of all color names?

Tags: python, colors, kivy

In Kivy, the widgets' `color` property allows enter its value as a string of a **color name**, too, e.g. in `.kv` file:

```
   Label:
       color: "red"
```

Is there a list of all possible color names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

```
from kivy.utils import colormap
# import dict with all CSS 3 Colors 
# like {'aliceblue':[0.9411764705882353, 0.9725490196078431, 1.0, 1.0]}

'aliceblue' in colormap 
# True
```

For the plot, see the end of this answer.

---

**Dictionary of colors**

The kivy [docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ColorProperty) mention that colors referenced by name are retrieved from an object called `colormap`. This object resides in `kivy.utils` as a variable storing a dictionary comprehension that iterates over another dictionary named `hex_colormap`:

```
colormap = {k: get_color_from_hex(v) for k, v in hex_colormap.items()}
```

The ultimate source for these dictionaries is referenced only indirectly in the docs ([link](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#ColorKeywords)). A better reference would be: [CSS 3 Colors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#svg-color) (recommended by the W3C).

At any rate, in order to retrieve all the valid color names, you can import either one of these objects:

```
from kivy.utils import hex_colormap, colormap

hex_colormap # name (key): hex (value)

{'aliceblue': '#f0f8ff',
 'antiquewhite': '#faebd7',
 ...
 'yellow': '#ffff00',
 'yellowgreen': '#9acd32'}

print('aliceblue' in hex_colormap)
# True (all colors in CSS3)

colormap # name (key): rgba (value)

{'aliceblue': [0.9411764705882353, 0.9725490196078431, 
               1.0, 1.0],
 'antiquewhite': [0.9803921568627451, 0.9215686274509803,
                  0.8431372549019608, 1.0],
 ...
 'yellow': [1.0, 1.0, 
            0.0, 1.0],
 'yellowgreen': [0.6039215686274509, 0.803921568627451,
                 0.19607843137254902, 1.0]}
 
print('rebeccapurple' in hex_colormap)
# False (only color added in CSS4)
```

<sub>* on "rebeccapurple": [Changes from Colors 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#changes-from-3).</sub>

**Plot**

The matplotlib [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html#helper-function-for-plotting) contain a nice function (`plot_colortable`) that you can copy/paste to plot a list of named colors. You can pass either one of the dictionaries to this function to get a nice sorted list of colors and their names.

```
plot_colortable(colormap) # add `sort_colors=False` for unsorted plot
plt.show()
```

*Result:*

[image: plot CSS 3 Colors]

Of course, this plot (showing Kivy's 147 named colors) is just the same as the plot already shown in the docs for [`mcolors.CSS4_COLORS`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html#css-colors) (containing CSS4's 148 colors), the only difference being that my plot is missing "rebeccapurple".

Comment: In Matplotlib version 3.6.3 the "rebeccapulple" color is not missing (there are 148 colors in `mcolors.CSS4_COLORS`), so you probably have an older one. — Nonetheless, Kivy still don't allow using this color name, and it is in concordance with Kivy docs: SVG 1.1, or – as you pointed – CSS3 color names, not CSS4 ones (with "rebeccapulple" added).

Comment: The antecedent of the anaphoric pronoun "it" in my last sentence is indeed ambiguous: I mean to indicate that "this plot" (i.e. *my* plot) is missing "rebeccapurple" ;). So, `mcolors.CSS4_COLORS` indeed has 148 colors (as it should), `colormap` has 147 (missing "rebeccapurple", because it was added only in CSS4, and Kivy hasn't yet added the color to `colormap`). This is why I am adding the plot *without* "rebeccapurple". I've rephrased the sentence, thanks.

Comment: Oh, so you **intentionally** omit this color. Now I understand, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. From the [Kivy’s documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html):

> Object colormap is used to retrieve color from color name and names definitions can be found at
> this [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#ColorKeywords).

It means that Kivy uses color names of W3C (WWW Consortium) Recommendation for SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) image format.

See the [4.4 Recognized color keyword names](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#ColorKeywords) part of its “[Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) 1.1 (Second Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/)” document.

There are 147 color names in it. Here is an excerpt from it:

[image]

and here I prepared an alphabetical list of all these 147 names from it:

> aliceblue, antiquewhite, aqua, aquamarine, azure, beige, bisque, black, blanchedalmond, blue, blueviolet, brown, burlywood, cadetblue, chartreuse, chocolate, coral, cornflowerblue, cornsilk, crimson, cyan, darkblue, darkcyan, darkgoldenrod, darkgray, darkgreen, darkgrey, darkkhaki, darkmagenta, darkolivegreen, darkorange, darkorchid, darkred, darksalmon, darkseagreen, darkslateblue, darkslategray, darkslategrey, darkturquoise, darkviolet, deeppink, deepskyblue, dimgray, dimgrey, dodgerblue, firebrick, floralwhite, forestgreen, fuchsia, gainsboro, ghostwhite, gold, goldenrod, gray, grey, green, greenyellow, honeydew, hotpink, indianred, indigo, ivory, khaki, lavender, lavenderblush, lawngreen, lemonchiffon, lightblue, lightcoral, lightcyan, lightgoldenrodyellow, lightgray, lightgreen, lightgrey, lightpink, lightsalmon, lightseagreen, lightskyblue, lightslategray, lightslategrey, lightsteelblue, lightyellow, lime, limegreen, linen, magenta, maroon, mediumaquamarine, mediumblue, mediumorchid, mediumpurple, mediumseagreen, mediumslateblue, mediumspringgreen, mediumturquoise, mediumvioletred, midnightblue, mintcream, mistyrose, moccasin, navajowhite, navy, oldlace, olive, olivedrab, orange, orangered, orchid, palegoldenrod, palegreen, paleturquoise, palevioletred, papayawhip, peachpuff, peru, pink, plum, powderblue, purple, red, rosybrown, royalblue, saddlebrown, salmon, sandybrown, seagreen, seashell, sienna, silver, skyblue, slateblue, slategray, slategrey, snow, springgreen, steelblue, tan, teal, thistle, tomato, turquoise, violet, wheat, white, whitesmoke, yellow, yellowgreen

Comment: @ouroboros1, nice, thanks. What not write it is as another answer and gain reputation from it?

Comment: I created that entire list in Python code as part of [an answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75052333/5987).

Comment: @ouroboros1, I don't want to gain points for your very useful comment – please post it as another answer, I'll appreciate it (and other people, I believe, too).

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody wants a tool/program that generates a list of colournames that can be searched in a Terminal or iterated over, it can be done with:

- **PIL**, see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75276756/2836621), or
- **ImageMagick**, using `identify -list color`

**Output**

```
Name                  Color                                         Compliance
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AliceBlue             srgb(240,248,255)                             SVG X11 XPM 
AntiqueWhite          srgb(250,235,215)                             SVG X11 XPM 
AntiqueWhite1         srgb(255,239,219)                             X11 
AntiqueWhite2         srgb(238,223,204)                             X11 
AntiqueWhite3         srgb(205,192,176)                             X11
...
...
```