# How to specify a color value for the color property in Kivy?

Tags: python, colors, kivy

In the majority of Kivy documents, courses and videos there is this prevalent form for specifying a value for the `color` property:

```
   Label:
       color: 0, 1, .8, .5
```

i.e. a tuple or list of 4 values for red, green, blue, and alpha channel components.

What are the all other possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

In Kivy, the widgets' `color` property is often (if not always) a member of the `ColorProperty` class. It means that there are these 5 possibilities for specifying its value:

1. as a collection of **3** float values between 0 and 1
   (for red, green, and blue components, respectively) for **full opaque colors**, e.g. in a `.kv` file

   ```
   Label:
       color: 0, 1, .8
   ```
2. as a collection of **4** float values between 0 and 1
   with possibility to control the **transparency** (alpha channel), too (the last, 4<sup>th</sup> item), e.g. for half transparency

   ```
   Label:
       color: 0, 1, .8, .5
   ```
3. as a string of **3** double-character values in the range 00 to FF hexadecimal (i.e. 0 to 255 decimal),
   in the form of `#rrggbb` (case-insensitive) for **full opaque color**

   ```
   Label:
       color: "#00ffcc"
   ```
4. as a string of **4** double-character values in the range 00 to FF hexadecimal (i.e. 0 to 255 decimal),
   in the form of `#rrggbbaa` (case-insensitive) with possibility to control the **transparency** (alpha channel), too:

   ```
   Label:
       color: "#00FFCC80"
   ```
5. as a string of a **color name**, e.g. for half transparency

   ```
   Label:
       color: "red"
   ```

---

*Note:*

You may find a list of *all possible 147 color names* in my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76418778/7023590).