# How to extract the specific colors from an image

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, k-means

I need some support in adding details to my code. In my code, I am just using 1 image (see attachment, called "Photo1").

When I run the whole code, it will give me the following output:

```
,"Dominant Colors:
['#263f6c', '#4c5d85', '#d3d6d8', '#9db1c6', '#7388a7']"
```

I don't want the output as codes, I want to know exactly which colors are the dominant colors (example: red, blue, black) and return it in a column called "extracted colors"

How can I add these details in my code?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

image_path = "Photo1.jpg"
num_colors = 5
num_clusters = 5

def get_dominant_colors(image_path, num_colors=10, num_clusters=5):
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = image.resize((200, 200))
    image = image.convert('RGB')
    img_array = np.array(image)
    pixels = img_array.reshape(-1, 3)
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, random_state=0)
    labels = kmeans.fit_predict(pixels)
    centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
    color_counts = {}
    for label in np.unique(labels):
        color = tuple(centers[label].astype(int))
        color_counts[color] = np.count_nonzero(labels == label)
    sorted_colors = sorted(color_counts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    dominant_colors = [color for color, count in sorted_colors[:num_colors]]
    color_occurrences = [count for color, count in sorted_colors[:num_colors]]
    dominant_colors_hex = ['#%02x%02x%02x' % color for color in dominant_colors]
    return dominant_colors_hex, color_occurrences

dominant_colors, color_occurrences = get_dominant_colors(image_path, num_colors, num_clusters)

print("Dominant Colors:")
print(dominant_colors)

palette_height = 100
palette_width = 100 * num_colors
palette = np.zeros((palette_height, palette_width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

start_x = 0
for color_hex in dominant_colors:
    color_rgb = tuple(int(color_hex[i:i+2], 16) for i in (1, 3, 5))
    end_x = start_x + 100
    palette[:, start_x:end_x] = color_rgb
    start_x = end_x

palette_image = Image.fromarray(palette)
palette_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(palette_image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

cv2.imshow("Palette", palette_bgr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: Please click [edit] and make sure your code is [mcve] - the formatting is currently wrong. Please also provide your images, else no-one can help.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have corrected the formatting. And I have attached the image as well.

Comment: You might check this for inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75006269/5987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possibilities is to use [webcolors](https://pypi.org/project/webcolors/) package. I modified your code to find the name of the closest matching color on the color palette:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import webcolors
from webcolors import CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES, hex_to_rgb

image_path = "Photo1.png"
num_colors = 5
num_clusters = 5

def get_dominant_colors(image_path, num_colors=10, num_clusters=5):
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = image.resize((200, 200))
    image = image.convert('RGB')
    img_array = np.array(image)
    pixels = img_array.reshape(-1, 3)
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, random_state=0)
    labels = kmeans.fit_predict(pixels)
    centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
    color_counts = {}
    for label in np.unique(labels):
        color = tuple(centers[label].astype(int))
        color_counts[color] = np.count_nonzero(labels == label)
    sorted_colors = sorted(color_counts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    dominant_colors = [color for color, count in sorted_colors[:num_colors]]
    color_occurrences = [count for color, count in sorted_colors[:num_colors]]
    dominant_colors_hex = ['#%02x%02x%02x' % color for color in dominant_colors]
    return dominant_colors_hex, color_occurrences

dominant_colors, color_occurrences = get_dominant_colors(image_path, num_colors, num_clusters)

def closest_color(hex):
    colors = {}
    for key, name in CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES.items():
        r_c, g_c, b_c = hex_to_rgb(key)
        rd = (int(hex[1:3], 16) - r_c) ** 2
        gd = (int(hex[3:5], 16) - g_c) ** 2
        bd = (int(hex[5:7], 16) - b_c) ** 2
        colors[(rd + gd + bd)] = name
    return colors[min(colors.keys())]
print("Dominant colors: ")

for col in dominant_colors:
    col_name = closest_color(col)
    print(col_name)

palette_height = 100
palette_width = 100 * num_colors
palette = np.zeros((palette_height, palette_width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

start_x = 0
for color_hex in dominant_colors:
    color_rgb = tuple(int(color_hex[i:i+2], 16) for i in (1, 3, 5))
    end_x = start_x + 100
    palette[:, start_x:end_x] = color_rgb
    start_x = end_x

palette_image = Image.fromarray(palette)
palette_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(palette_image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

cv2.imshow("Palette", palette_bgr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You can swap the color mapping from CSS3 to [HTML4](https://www.webstandards.org/learn/reference/charts/color_names/index.html), for example. It includes names for the 16 base colors [Here you can find more.](https://webcolors.readthedocs.io/en/1.5/contents.html)
Just replace the line

```
for key, name in CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES.items():
```

with

```
for key, name in HTML4_HEX_TO_NAMES.items():
```

Comment: Thanks! Works very good. This output gave me the result: darkslategray, darkslateblue, lightgray, darkgray, lightslategray. How can I avoid these colors and get the main colors (blue, gray) as output? I had tried a photo with a red color, it gave me the output "brickred", I just wanted red as output.

Comment: @user20649218 I have edited the post, please check it

Comment: Very nice, works as well. Thanks.

Comment: I've been struggling another problem. So the outcome of this code gives me the output: "Dominant colors: gray maroon silver gray black". How can I create a dataframe of this with a column and row and have the output on the first row? The column should be called "Extracted colors". So in case if I use 10 images in this code, I will be having 10 rows with the output.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up using when I had to figure something similar out.

[image: Photo of Tool]

The above image shows that the .HTML table it generates upon hovering show sthe frequency and color name / hex value of the color. Also, if you click the color block it'll copy that hex value.

```
[import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from webcolors import CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES, hex_to_rgb

# Specify the path to the image file
image_path = "Picture.png"

def get_dominant_colors(image_path, num_colors=10, num_clusters=5):
    """
    Utilizes KMeans clustering to identify dominant colors in an image.
    """
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = image.resize((200, 200))
    image = image.convert('RGB')

    img_array = np.array(image)
    pixels = img_array.reshape(-1, 3)
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, random_state=0)
    labels = kmeans.fit_predict(pixels)
    centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
    color_counts = {}
    for label in np.unique(labels):
        color = tuple(centers\[label\].astype(int))
        color_counts\[color\] = np.count_nonzero(labels == label)
    sorted_colors = sorted(color_counts.items(), key=lambda x: x\[1\], reverse=True)
    dominant_colors = \[color for color, count in sorted_colors\[:num_colors\]\]
    color_occurrences = \[count for color, count in sorted_colors\[:num_colors\]\]
    dominant_colors_hex = \['#%02x%02x%02x' % color for color in dominant_colors\]
    return dominant_colors_hex, color_occurrences

def closest_color(hex):
    """
    Finds the closest matching color name from CSS3 colors.
    """
    colors = {}
    for key, name in CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES.items():
        r_c, g_c, b_c = hex_to_rgb(key)
        rd = (int(hex\[1:3\], 16) - r_c) ** 2
        gd = (int(hex\[3:5\], 16) - g_c) ** 2
        bd = (int(hex\[5:7\], 16) - b_c) ** 2
        colors\[(rd + gd + bd)\] = name
    return colors\[min(colors.keys())\]

def rgb_to_hex(rgb):
    """
    Converts RGB tuple to hexadecimal color representation.
    """
    return '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(rgb\[0\], rgb\[1\], rgb\[2\])

def get_colors(image_path):
    """
    Retrieves all distinct colors present in the image.
    """
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = image.resize((200, 200))
    image = image.convert('RGB')

    # Fetch pixel colors
    pixels = list(image.getdata())

    # Identify unique colors
    unique_colors = list(set(pixels))

    return unique_colors

# Obtain dominant colors
dominant_colors_hex, color_occurrences = get_dominant_colors(image_path)

# Display extracted color names
print("Extracted Colors:")
for col_hex in dominant_colors_hex:
    col_name = closest_color(col_hex)
    print(col_name)

# Write distinct colors and their counts to a text file
with open(image_path.split('.')\[0\] + "_Color_List.txt", 'w') as f:
    for col_hex, col_occ in zip(dominant_colors_hex, color_occurrences):
        col_name = closest_color(col_hex)
        print(f"{col_name} \[{col_occ}\]", file=f)

# Convert colors to hexadecimal representation
distinct_colors = get_colors(image_path)
distinct_colors_hex = \[rgb_to_hex(color) for color in distinct_colors\]

# Generate HTML color table
html_content = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<style>\ntable {\nborder-collapse: collapse;\n}\ntd {\nborder: 1px solid black;\nwidth: 15px;\nheight: 15px;\n}\n</style>\n<script>\nfunction copyColor(hex) {\n  var dummy = document.createElement('textarea');\n  document.body.appendChild(dummy);\n  dummy.value = hex;\n  dummy.select();\n  document.execCommand('copy');\n  document.body.removeChild(dummy);\n}\n</script>\n</head>\n<body>\n<table>"
html_content += "\n<tr>"
for color, count, hex_code in zip(dominant_colors_hex, color_occurrences, distinct_colors_hex):
    color_name = closest_color(color)
    html_content += f"\n<td title='{color_name} ({hex_code}), {count} times' style='background-color:{color}' onclick='copyColor(\"{color}\")'></td>"
html_content += "\n</tr>\n</table>\n</body>\n</html>"

# Write HTML content to file
with open(image_path.split('.')\[0\] + "_Color_Table.html", 'w') as f:
    f.write(html_content)][1]
```